# Navigation Bar Dropdown Issue

Tags: html, css, checkbox, drop-down-menu

I am trying to make a navigation menu using only CSS (since I don't know JavaScript), that has a sub menu that appears when the top level link is clicked, and then disappears when the top level link is clicked again. I have used checkboxes and labels to make this happen.

It works well, but there is a small problem. If you click on "menu 2" the dropdown appears which is fine. But if you hover away from "menu 2" and back again, the sub menu reappears without having clicked on "menu 2" first.

How can I make it so that when you hover away from menu item 2 and back again, "menu 2" has to be clicked on again to make the sub menu appear?

[here is a codepen I made to demonstrate](https://codepen.io/jamesdavidson/pen/aVJBEz?editors=1100)

```css
nav {
  width: 200px;
}

nav ul {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
}

nav>ul>li {
  float: left;
}

nav a {
  height: 40px;
  width: 100px;
  display: block;
  background: lightblue;
  text-decoration: none;
  line-height: 40px;
  text-align: center;
  color: black;
}

nav>ul>li>a:hover {
  background: skyblue;
}

nav ul ul a {
  height: 20px;
  background: lightgreen;
  line-height: 20px;
}

nav ul ul a:hover {
  background: limegreen;
}

nav label {
  display: block;
}

nav input {
  display: none;
}

nav ul ul {
  display: none;
}

nav li:hover input:checked+ul {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Menu 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><label for="submenucb">Menu 2&#9662;</label></a>
      <input id="submenucb" type="checkbox">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Sub Menu 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Sub Menu 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Sub Menu 1</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: why not just take the hover off it: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/LOWxmQ?editors=1100

Comment: I want the hover so that the sub menu disappears when the mouse is moved away. Otherwise, if I have more that one dropdown on the menu, they could all be visible at the same time. I want just one dropdown menu to be visible at any time.

Comment: I think then, you should remove the input and only open it on hover - if you have a mixture of opening it on click and hover then it will get confusing for users - I probably would use it once and then it would become a usability issue that would stop me using the site - https://codepen.io/anon/pen/LOWxmQ?editors=1100

Comment: I want the behaviour to be: if you click on "menu 2" the dropdown appears, then if you hover away it disappears.  Then if you hover on "menu 2" again, you need to click on it to make the sub menu appear again instead of it already being open.

Comment: You can't do that with css alone as you cannot uncheck a checkbox without clicking, unless you use some js

Answer (score 0):

You can remove `:hover` from the selector. The dropdown will only appear when the item is clicked.

```
 input:checked+ul {
      display: block;
    }
```

```css
nav {
  width: 200px;
}

nav ul {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
}

nav>ul>li {
  float: left;
}


/* top level links */

nav a {
  height: 40px;
  width: 100px;
  display: block;
  background: lightblue;
  text-decoration: none;
  line-height: 40px;
  text-align: center;
  color: black;
}

nav>ul>li>a:hover {
  background: skyblue;
}


/* sub level links */

nav ul ul a {
  height: 20px;
  background: lightgreen;
  line-height: 20px;
}

nav ul ul a:hover {
  background: limegreen;
}


/* dropdown behaviour */

nav label {
  display: block;
}

nav input {
  display: none;
}

nav ul ul {
  display: none;
}

input:checked+ul {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Menu 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><label for="submenucb">Menu 2&#9662;</label></a>
      <input id="submenucb" type="checkbox">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Sub Menu 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Sub Menu 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Sub Menu 1</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```